# Issues related to Session state off

Tags: asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, session-state

In my web config I have session state off

```
<sessionState mode="Off" />
```

When I run my application I am seeing *ASP.net_sessionid* cookie being generated with expiration expiration *"When I close my browser".* 
[image]

1 .How this cookie is generated if my session state is off?

2. How can I change the session timeout in this case (when session state is off)?
3. What is the relation between session timeout and the *ASP.net_sessionid* cookie expiry time?
4. If my session state is off will my Session End event in Global.asax.cs fire?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the browser is displaying a cached version of the page. If it is IE check Tools - Options - General - Browsing History and click on the "Settings" button. Make sure that "Check for newer versions of stores pages" is set to "Every time I visit the webpage".